# Dojo lang.mixin for loop only writing last item to object

Tags: dojo

I am using dojo lang.mixin to write items to an object but it seems to only write the last key:value to the object. Which makes me think lang.mixin just writes one key:value at a time. Is there a way to keep appending key:values to the object?

```
for (var i = 0; i < selection.length; ++i) {
   lang.mixin(myObj, {
     selection[i].Type: selection[i].Name //always gives me last index in loop
   })
}
```

Comment: you want to mix an array of value you mean ?

Comment: Well each key has to be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While adding properties to object the properties needs to be unique.

`lang.mixin` is used to update the target object with source object. If the property "name" matches with the source, then the property is updated else the property is added to the target. The nested objects will not be mixed. For example:

```
var a = { 
    name:"John",
    account : { type : "student", email : "a@xyz.com" }
};
var b = { 
    Age: "18 yrs",
    account: { phone : "66589956" }
};
lang.mixin(a, b); // here the type and email will be lost for account property
```

In your case, if you consider the `selection[i].Type` is "type" then your code will behave something like below

```
for (var i = 0; i < selection.length; ++i) {
    lang.mixin(myObj, {
        "type" : selection[i].Name
    });
}
```

So the same property will be updated on each cycle of the loop, unless the `selection[i].Type` value is different.

```js
require(["dojo/_base/lang"], function(lang){
  var selection = [ { Type:"A", Name:"Letter A" },
                    { Type:"B", Name:"Letter B" },
                    { Type:"C", Name:"Letter C" },
                    { Type:"D", Name:"Letter D" }
                   ];
  
  var myObj = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < selection.length; ++i) {
     var tmp = {};
     tmp[selection[i].Type] = selection[i].Name;
     lang.mixin(myObj, tmp);
  }
  console.log(myObj);
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.11.2/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```